# JBox2D - how to get vertex positions?

Tags: java, box2d, jbox2d

I've created a triangle for jbox2d...

```
public void createTri(){ 

    PolygonDef shape = new PolygonDef();

    shape.density = 2.0f;

    shape.friction = 0.8f;
    shape.restitution = 0.3f;
    shape.addVertex( new Vec2(35/RATE,35/RATE) );
    shape.addVertex( new Vec2(65/RATE,35/RATE) );
    shape.addVertex( new Vec2(45/RATE,55/RATE) );

    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.position.set(50/RATE, 50/RATE);
    bodyT= world.createBody(bodyDef);
    bodyT.createShape(shape);
    bodyT.setMassFromShapes();
}
```

... but when drawing it on canvas, how to I get position of all the vertexes?

with bodyT.getPosition().x and .y I can get only the center spot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about JBox2D but in the actual Box2D lib there is PolygonShape.GetVertex()

```
  //Returns a Vec2 (the coordinates) of a vertex given its index
  const b2Vec2& GetVertex(int32 index) const;
```

So according to your code, I think calling shape.GetVertex(1) returns the second vertex you added.